# Keyclaok API: won't assign realm role to the created user

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to create a new user and assign it an 'internal' realm-role via Keycloak API. The realm-role is already created as you can [see](https://imgur.com/Ir5R1pG), the user is being created but it doesn't assign the realm role to that user. What am I doing wrong? Should I assign the role via a second keycloak API request? Then what's the point of providing 'realmRoles' body param in the first place?

```
POST admin/realms/{realm}/users
{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
    username: john.doe,
    realmRoles: ['internal']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must  assign it in a seperate step.
First get the role-Mapping

```
GET admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}/role-mappings/realm/available?first=0&max=11
```

Then pick the Mapping and assign it

```
POST admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}/role-mappings/realm
[
{"id":"4d485565-dd2c-41e0-8739-951c962f0cfd",
"name":"offline_access",
"description":"${role_offline-access}",
"composite":false,
"clientRole":false,
"containerId":"{realm}"}
]
```

The user ID can be obtained as result from the create request
[image]

BTW if you run the developer tools of your browser and perform the actions "by hand" you should be able to figure out the requests in the network-tab.

Comment: It seems I also need a separate step to get the user id because the first call doesn't return anything when you create the user. Such a shame

Comment: I also need to make an additional request to get the role id. This is ridiculous

Comment: The User-Id is returned in the location-parameter of the response

Comment: The response is empty @csbrogi. Where do I find the location-parameter, specifically?

Comment: I added it to my answer. What programming language are you using?

Comment: javascript (next-js)

Comment: I was able to get the user ID from location headers. Still silly that I have to make additional request to get ID of the role I want to assign user to... Is there any other way to assign role using its name, without giving it role id?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no way, but you can find the complete API at https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.1.1/rest-api/index.html#_role_mapper_resource